# track the user with camera in javascript and getuserMedia

Tags: javascript, canvas, face-detection, webrtc, getusermedia

I need track to user with camera and I found the headtrackr library (https://github.com/auduno/headtrackr/) and is very useful because you can determine the body with the head reference, but give me problems when I cover my face with something or if I don´t have shirt.  What I really need is to separate the body from the background.
Perhaps with a blending mode or something like that? any idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Possibly the first ever question on Stackoverflow where a key issue has been shirtless support.

Comment: hahahha maybe. Is not my priority in this project but is an option